# What is the correct way to apply existing virtual environment based on WSL into Pycham?

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

What I am trying to do is applying an existing virtual environment made by WSL into a project's interpreter on Pycharm. But looks like it doesn't work well.

What I did is Setting -> Project interpreter -> Add Python interpreter -> And I selected WSL and then I chose a file named `python3.6` inside `venv/bin/python3.6`

But there is an error

> Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter: Empty output from generator3.py for wsl://UBUNTU1804/mnt/c/Users/project/venv/bin/python3.6

and scanning installed packages never finished.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you have latest Windows 10 version the [official way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/) is to mount the wsl distro drive as a network drive.